# TestRunner InitilisationError

Tags: maven, cucumber, bdd

I am new to  the Gherkin / cucumber BDD.  I have been trying to create a framework using Maven, TestNG and Cucumber. I created feature file, StepDefinitiions and TestRunner.  When I run feature file my scenarios are executed successfully.  However, when I try to run using 'TestRunner' I am getting **InitialisationError**  I believe I have added all required dependencies in Maven-POM.xml

I am attaching screenshot of error:
[TestRunnerInitialisationError](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qzhhL.png)

I am attaching additional information

**Project Sttructure**
[Project Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JvBAT.png)

**POM.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>auto</groupId>
  <artifactId>AAFramework</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <name>AAFramework</name>
  <!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
  <url>http://www.example.com</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>
  
<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/java/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
    </resources>

  <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
        <configuration>
          <suiteXmlFiles>
            <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
          </suiteXmlFiles>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

 <dependencies>
 
     <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.13</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/gherkin -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>gherkin</artifactId>
        <version>15.0.2</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.141.59</version>
    </dependency>
    

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.testng/testng -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>7.3.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    
    <!-- Log4j dependencies: https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/maven-artifacts.html#Using_Log4j_in_your_Apache_Maven_build -->
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.13.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.13.3</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <!-- For Screenshots: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-io -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.aventstack/extentreports -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
        <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.3</version>
    </dependency>
    
    
    
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-java -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
        <version>6.6.0</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-junit -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
        <version>6.6.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-testng -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-testng</artifactId>
        <version>6.6.0</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/cucumber-testng -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
        </dependency>
    
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

**Testng.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "https://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite" parallel = "tests">
 <listeners>
        <listener class-name="aaframework.Listeners"/>
 </listeners>

  <test  name="AmazonHomeLins">
    <classes>
      <class name="cucumberOptions.TestRunner"/>
    </classes>
  </test> 
</suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

**Feature File**

```
Feature: Verify Amazon India homne page header links are working and redirected to respective pages

  Scenario: Mobile link is working on Amazon home page
    Given I am on Amazon India home page
    When I click on Mobiles link
    Then I am redirected to Mobiles web page

  Scenario: Best Sellers link is working on Amazon home page
    Given I am on Amazon India home page
    When I click on 'BestSellers' link
    Then I am redirected to Best Sellers web page
```

**Step Definitions**

```
package stepDefs;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.testng.Assert;

import io.cucumber.java.en.Given;
import io.cucumber.java.en.Then;
import io.cucumber.java.en.When;
import pageObject.HomePagePF;
import resources.Base;

public class AmazonHome extends Base{
    public WebDriver driver;
    HomePagePF hp;
    
    
    @Given("I am on Amazon India home page")
    public void i_am_on_amazon_india_home_page() throws IOException {
        // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
        driver = initialiseBrowser();
        driver.get(prop.getProperty("url"));
    }

    @When("I click on Mobiles link")
    public void i_click_on_mobiles_link() {
        // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
        hp  = new HomePagePF(driver);
        hp.getMobiles().click();
    }

    @Then("I am redirected to Mobiles web page")
    public void i_am_redirected_to_mobiles_web_page() throws InterruptedException {
        // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        String actualMobile = driver.getTitle();
//      System.out.println(actualMobile);
        String expectedMobile = "Mobile Phones: Buy New Mobiles Online at Best Prices in India | Buy Cell Phones Online - Amazon.in";
        Assert.assertEquals(actualMobile, expectedMobile);
        driver.close();
    }
     

    @When("^I click on 'BestSellers' link$")
    public void i_click_on_bestsellers_link() throws Throwable {
        hp  = new HomePagePF(driver);
        hp.getBestSellersLink().click();
    }

    @Then("^I am redirected to Best Sellers web page$")
    public void i_am_redirected_to_best_sellers_web_page() throws Throwable {
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        String actualTitle = driver.getTitle();
//      System.out.println(actualTitle);
        String expectedTitle = "Amazon.in Bestsellers: The most popular items on Amazon";
        Assert.assertEquals(actualTitle, expectedTitle);
        driver.close();
    }
}
```

**TestRunner**

```
package cucumberOptions;

import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import io.cucumber.junit.Cucumber;
import io.cucumber.junit.CucumberOptions;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(features = "/src/test/java/features", 
                glue= {"src/test/java/stepDefs"})
public class TestRunner {

}
```

Comment: u  r using a junit runner with testng. convert to a testng runner.